# Get database type from connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am trying to change my `sql` queries based on the type of database.

Is there a way to understand the database provider (`Sql Server`, `MySql`, `Oracle`, `Sqlite`) by having the connection string as your parameter?

And by that I do not mean parsing and splitting the connection string and searching for words.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this web site: [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)?

All the most popular DBs' connection strings are listed there - you can see the differences in their formats.

E.G. Oracle:

```
Data Source=MyOracleDB;Integrated Security=yes;
```

MySQL:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

SQL Server:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

From these examples you can say that you can define Oracle DB by `Data Source` substring, then tell the difference between MySql and SQL Server by string `Uid` and `User Id` respectively and so on.

Comment: yes I am aware of connectionstrings.com. Your solution works but as I mentioned, I was wondering if there is an easier way that parsing strings?

Comment: Too much heuristics. IIRC SQL Server supports both `uid` and `user id` syntax. Furthermore, there's SQLNCLI* which also supports at least `uid`.

Comment: @Pedram, you mean using some library that does it for you? Because connection string is just a string, what else can be done with it except parsing for special substrings?

Comment: @ZuoLi I am looking for some library that does this. Do you have any suggestion?